# Check File Exist with different user

Tags: .net, vb.net, vba

I have created .exe file to check whether file exist or not on Shared Path..

below is the vb.net code

Here, the issue is..the users who does not have access on mentioned shared path they are not able to check status and they have to run exe with Run As different user id who have access...

Any solution if I can bind credentials inside the code so that everybody can check status..???

```
Try

Dim curFile As String = "\\SharedPath\Data\testFile.txt"
    If (File.Exists(curFile) ) Then
        lblFileStatus.Text = "Received"
    Else
        lblFileStatus.Text = "File not Received"
    End If
    Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Comment: thats a bad practice - i would write some service that can check that for you.

Comment: give read permission on the directory to a group which contains all the target audience.

Comment: if someone have no access .. keep it like that .. you don't have to change the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method below is not recommended at all, I completely agree with the commentators above, but as a pure exersize you can try this.

First declare calls to Windows API:

```
#Region "Windows API Declarations"

    'used in calling WNetAddConnection2
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> Private Structure NETRESOURCE
        Public dwScope As Integer
        Public dwType As Integer
        Public dwDisplayType As Integer
        Public dwUsage As Integer
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> Public lpLocalName As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> Public lpRemoteName As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> Public lpComment As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> Public lpProvider As String
    End Structure

    'WIN32API - WNetAddConnection2

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Helper function to call Win32API function
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="i_sPath">Path to a file to authenticate</param>
    ''' <param name="i_sPassword">User ID</param>
    ''' <param name="i_sUserID">Password</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Sub WNetAddConnection2AEx(ByVal i_sPath As String, ByVal i_sPassword As String, ByVal i_sUserID As String)
        Dim nr(1) As NETRESOURCE
        nr(0).lpRemoteName = i_sPath.Substring(0, i_sPath.IndexOf("\", 2))
        nr(0).lpLocalName = "" 'local mashine
        nr(0).dwType = 1 'disk
        nr(0).dwDisplayType = 0
        nr(0).dwScope = 0
        nr(0).dwUsage = 0
        nr(0).lpComment = ""
        nr(0).lpProvider = ""
        Dim iErr As Integer = WNetAddConnection2A(nr, i_sPassword, i_sUserID, 0)
        If iErr > 0 Then Throw New Exception("Can not connect to share folder: " & i_sPath)
    End Sub

    <DllImport("mpr.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function WNetAddConnection2A( _
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> ByVal lpNetResource As NETRESOURCE(), _
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal lpPassword As String, _
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal lpUserName As String, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Integer) As Integer

    End Function

    <DllImport("mpr.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function WNetCancelConnection2A( _
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal lpName As String, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal fForce As Integer) As Integer

    End Function

    '{**** Declare signatures for Win32 LogonUser and CloseHandle APIs
    <DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function LogonUser(ByVal userID As String, _
                                      ByVal domain As String, _
                                      ByVal password As String, _
                                      ByVal logonType As LogonSessionType, _
                                      ByVal LogonProv As LogonProvider, _
                                      ByRef token As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function CloseHandle(ByVal handle As IntPtr) As Boolean

    End Function

    Private Enum LogonSessionType As Integer
        Interactive = 2
        Network
        Batch
        Service
        NetworkCleartext = 8
        NewCredentials
    End Enum

    Private Enum LogonProvider As Integer
        WinDefault = 0  'default for platform (use this!)
        WinNT35       'sends smoke signals to authority
        WinNT40       'uses NTLM
        WinNT50       'negotiates Kerb or NTLM
    End Enum
    '**** }

#End Region
```

With declarations like this you can make following calls:

```
'Open secondary login with different credentials
WNetAddConnection2AEx(curFile, sPassword, sUserID)

'*** Here do your stuff with the sPath

'Cleanup
WNetCancelConnection2A(curFile.Substring(0, curFile.IndexOf("\", 2)), 0, -1)
```